# Change the origin of the marker in google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, marker

[image]

I've used a custom marker to give my current location but the problem is that it shows the bottom of part of the image at the location which I've entered.

I want the center of the image to be at the location which I've entered!

I'm using GoogleMap and mapFragment for this purpose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MarkerOptions.anchor()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float,%20float)):

```
MarkerOptions options;
[...]
options.anchor( 0.5f, 0.5f );   //set anchor point in center
map.addMarker( options );
```